# find file directory with the shell

Tags: linux, shell, find

I want to find the directory 'thimthumb'.

I've a lot of wordpress installations and the search string should be a theme.
In some communities they said `thimthumb` has a virus and so I want to search it.

I'm root and try to use `find` but I did something wrong. Can someone create me the `find` string?

```
find /thimthumb   # that's it?!
```

Comment: ``locate thimthumb`` if ``locate`` is properly installed at your site. It updates the database generally once a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find -name ‘thimthumb’ -print` From within the directory you want to search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `find` command:

```
find / -type d -name 'thimthumb' -delete
```

Comment: I would drop the ``-delete``, and first just have a look :)

Comment: Right, always a good idea to check with `find / -type d -name 'thimthumb'`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the "mlocate" package installed you can run:

```
locate thimthumb
```

if it doesnt return anything you may need to update the database

```
updatedb
```